# Import multiple files into a table

Tags: sql-server, powershell, import

I have a directory full of files. They're SQL scripts, but I don't want to run them. I want to import the contents of the script files into a table in my database to be run at a later time. Each file would have its own row in the table.

I'm currently working with Powershell, but if there's another easier method that doesn't use third party software then I would be open to that as well.

Originally I started to write code that would loop through the files, use StreamReader to get the contents, then build an insert statement to execute. I realized though that there might be big problems with embedded quotes in the files, etc.

Thanks for any advice that you can give!

Comment: Please tell us more about the scripts

Comment: Why would there be problems with embedded quotes? Can you not use a parameterised query or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @bernd_k - They have text in them. They are not excessively large. I don't know what else you would need to know, but if you have a specific question, please let me know.

Comment: @Martin - Does Powershell have parameterized queries?

Comment: Ah right. No idea. Are the scripts somewhere visible to the server? Can you load them in with `SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\scripts\foo.sql', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you remove the embedded quotes and mark them as logical section to-be replaced 
by either by `String.Replace(old_str,new_str)` or tsql `REPLACE` in your logic ? Below sample shows 
`<condition_string>` marker so you know you have take special care of it.

```
declare @finalQuery nvarchar(1000)

SET @finalQuery = 
(SELECT REPLACE ((
   SELECT REPLACE ((
      SELECT  REPLACE('Select <column_names> from <table_name> where 
                              <condition_string>' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,
      '<column_names>', 
      'ID,[name]' )),
   '<table_name>',
   '[MyTable]')),

'<condition_string>',
'[name] like ''%John%'''));

EXEC(@finalQuery);

GO
```

Comment: I ended up doing a $string.Replace in Powershell just to get it working so that I could test other aspects, but it's actually working well, so I'm going to stick with it for now.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you're working with files in a database, you either want to reference them rather than importing the full contents (so you just store a path to the file on a physical volume) or you would store them as BLOBs (Binary Large Objects).  If doing the latter, you can zip them too.

The downside of these techniques is that you can't just search them with a SQL query, but you don't say whether that is an issue for you?

Comment: You misunderstood the question. The OP wants to store SQL read from a file into a column in a table, and later execute the contents of that column as SQL.

Comment: As Ken says, I need the file contents to be available in plain text. I also need the database to be fully contained - I can't ship around a directory of scripts along with the database, maintaining paths, etc.